# Nginx 502 error after Watchtower pulls new nodejs image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-pull, docker-push, docker-watchtower

This is my common **docker-dcompose.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  cron:
    container_name: cron
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./containers/cron
    depends_on:
      - server
    links:
      - server

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always

  server: # nodejs server
    image: my-docker-hub-account/server
    container_name: server
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./containers/server
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

And this is my staging **docker-compose.staging.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build:
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=staging
      context: ./containers/server
    command: node build/index.js
    image: my-docker-hub-account/server:staging
    env_file:
      - .env.common
      - .env.staging

  nginx:
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./containers/nginx/staging:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./ssl/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot:ro
      - ./ssl/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt

  watchtower:
    container_name: watchtower
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    environment:
      - REPO_USER=my-docker-hub-account
      - REPO_PASS=pass
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
      - WATCHTOWER_REMOVE_VOLUMES=true
      # - WATCHTOWER_INCLUDE_RESTARTING=true
      # - WATCHTOWER_REVIVE_STOPPED=true
      # - WATCHTOWER_ROLLING_RESTART=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --interval 30 --include-stopped server
```

After I make push of the newly build image and then pull on my DigitalOcean droplet, I get **Nginx 502 error** on hitting the same url. In order to get it work, I have to **compose up** again the app

Thank you mates in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these lines of code:

**com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable: true** (in services/server and services/nginx)

**com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.depends-on: 'server'** (in services/nginx)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    ... rest of the props
    labels:
      com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable: true

  nginx:
    ... rest of the props
    labels:
      com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable: true
      com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.depends-on: 'server'

  watchtower:
    ... rest of the props
    environment:
      - REPO_USER=my-docker-hub-account
      - REPO_PASS=pass
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
      - WATCHTOWER_REMOVE_VOLUMES=true
      - WATCHTOWER_REVIVE_STOPPED=true
      - WATCHTOWER_INCLUDE_RESTARTING=true
      - WATCHTOWER_INCLUDE_STOPPED=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --interval 30 nginx server
```